# Iterating through all div elements of a class using phantomjs

Tags: phantomjs

i have to iterate through all div elements of a class and get the inner html of those elements.How to do this using phantomjs?

Comment: Phantomjs is javascript, so you would do it the normal javascript way. You could also inject jquery which would make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

try using, evaluate & document.queryselectorAll